# How to get or create a Token

Tags: c#, asp.net, security, token, access-token

I am trying a token tutorial with web-api and I'm a little confuse, I can't figure how to get my Token, according to the tutorial the token comes from endpoint of Web Api, but I dont understand what is the specific function that produce the token or how to call it so I will get a token back to `GetToken()`, here some code:

#### class Startup

```
public void ConfigureAuth(IAppBuilder app)
        {                                    
            app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions());            app.UseExternalSignInCookie(DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ExternalCookie);         
            string PublicClientId = "self";
            OAuthAuthorizationServerOptions OAuthOptions = new OAuthAuthorizationServerOptions
            {
                TokenEndpointPath = new PathString("/Token"),
                Provider = new   PureApi.Provider.ApplicationOAuthProvider(PublicClientId),
                AuthorizeEndpointPath = new PathString("/api/Login"),
                AccessTokenExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromDays(14),
                AllowInsecureHttp = true
            };             
            app.UseOAuthBearerTokens(OAuthOptions);                                    
        }
```

#### my LoginController

```
static string GetToken(string userName, string password)
        {                var pairs = new List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>                                  
        {new KeyValuePair<string, string>( "grant_type", "password" ), 
         new KeyValuePair<string, string>( "username",userName ), 
         new KeyValuePair<string, string> ( "Password", password ) };
            var content = new FormUrlEncodedContent(pairs);
            using (var client = new HttpClient())
            {
                var response =                 client.PostAsync("http://localhost:2188/api/Test",content).Result;
                return response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
            }                                
        }
```

#### class Provider

```
public override Task TokenEndpoint(OAuthTokenEndpointContext context)
        { foreach (KeyValuePair<string, string> property in          context.Properties.Dictionary)
  { context.AdditionalResponseParameters.Add(property.Key,property.Value);
            }
            return Task.FromResult<object>(null);
        }
```